# Disable SSLv2 for Azure websites (DROWN vulnerability)

Tags: azure, ssl

How can we disable SSLv2 for Azure websites?

Reason for this is the DROWN attack SSL vulnerability: https://drownattack.com/

[Here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/how-to-disable-ssl-3-0-in-azure-websites-roles-and-virtual-machines/) I read instructions for disabling SSLv3 (earlier SSL issue) and now it is automatically disabled but cannot find a guide for disabling SSLv2.

Edit: My example report from [drownattack](https://test.drownattack.com) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1tVu.jpg and [SSL-labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V0lZ.jpg 
What is strange is that SSL-labs says that SSL 2.0 is not enabled for my site.

Thanks

Comment: Is your domain vulnerable? SSLv2 should have been disabled by default and the guide you linked to does disable SSLv2 explicitly ("Ensure SSL 2.0 disabled for client / server")

Comment: Drownattack says that my domain is vulnerable (please view Edit). 
Is SSLv2 disabled by default on Azure?
Guide has script to disable SSLv2 for Web Roles/Worker Roles. Can this script also be used for websites?

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit.

Problem is not with Azure, SSL v2 is disabled there.

We also have 1 other server (at a hosting provider) and there SSL v2 was enabled -> and that is why I was getting my domain is DROWN vulnerable.